# Inserting into mysql database using jsp throwing exception

Tags: mysql, database, jsp, jdbc

I am trying to store information from a registration form page to the corresponding database but the code is throwing the exception as stated 'unable to connect to database' I am a beginner and having a hard time trying to figure out what's going wrong in this. Can somebody please help?

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
<head>  
<meta charset="utf-8">  
<title>Sign Up</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reg.css">
</head>  
<body> 

<%
  String name = request.getParameter("name");
  String email = request.getParameter("email");
  String password = request.getParameter("password");
  String date = request.getParameter("date");
  String sex = request.getParameter("sex");

  Connection con = null;
  PreparedStatement ps = null;

  String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/table";
  String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  String user = "root";
  String pass = "";

  Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();

       try {

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, user, pass);

          String queryString = "INSERT INTO detail(name,password,email,date,sex) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

          ps = con.prepareStatement(queryString);
                ps.setString(1, name);
          ps.setString(2, password);
        ps.setString(3, email);
        ps.setString(4, date);
          ps.setString(5, sex);

          int updateQuery = ps.executeUpdate();
                        if (updateQuery != 0) { 
                            out.println("Successful Registration");
                         }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
        out.println("Unable to connect to database.");

           }
        finally {
            // close all the connections.
            ps.close();
            con.close();
         }
 %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: SCRIPTLETS! I use them last time in 2001! Why are you even using this? You should move to JSP tags as soon as you can (at least) or JSF (better).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have you included driver jar file in your project ?
2. At  `String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/table";` is table is your database name which you want to connect?
3. At

   ```
    catch (Exception ex) {
                out.println("Unable to connect to database.");

          }
   ```

include `ex.printStackTrace()` which will show you exact error.

Comment: thank youuu! the stacktrace helped me to find that the form was sending a null value to a NOT NULL field.

Answer (score 0):

Well... "unable to connect to database" means exactly that. Your JSP could not connect to the database.

Please add the full stack trace (error) in your question. That way it will be clearer what the problem is.

Off the top of my head, the possible culprits are:

1. **You don't have the driver loaded in your JEE container**. Did you add the database driver?
2. **Your driver is not properly configured**. Did you specify the correct "driver class" when adding the driver?
3. **Your URL is wrong**. Please check the value of the URL. Is it well-formed? Follow the exact format as the example one and insert your specific values.
4. **There's no database actually running** at that HOST:PORT. Was the database created?
5. **Your credentials are wrong**, disabled, or don't even exist yet. Check your username and password with your DBA. Do you have the right ones?

So, if you have checked already that and you think you have all those good, check the connection using a standalone client first. That way you'll see if the connection can be established. I would recommend **Squirrel SQL Client** or Eclipse's **Data Source Explorer**. Give them a try to check you have the right parameters.

Once you check your connection with a local client, everything should work in the JEE container.